# I want to know is it okay if i will use following method of memory allocation?

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to know is it okay if i will use following method? There is no syntax errors and any warnings but i want to know is there any memory problems?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test {
    int* x;
public:
    test(int *n) { this->x = new int(*n); }
    inline int get() { return *x; }
    ~test() { delete x; }
};

int main(void) {
while(1){
    test a(new int(3));
    cout << a.get() << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are violating the rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: You are leaking memory on `a` creation

Comment: So how can i change it to not violate rules ?

Comment: Simply read the rule of three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code:

- your class violates [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)
- you are leaking memory when create `a`

In this code:

```
test a(new int(3));
```

you dynamically allocate `int` with value 3 and pass to `a` ctor which uses value and creates it's own dynamically allocated `int`. After that this memory is leaked. If you want to pass dynamically allocated data to a class use a smart  pointer:

```
class test {
    std::unique_ptr<int> x;
public:
    test(std::unique_ptr<int> n) : x( std::move( n ) ) {  }
    int get() const { return *x; }
};

int main()
{
    x a( std::make_unique<int>( 3 ) ); // since c++14
    x a( std::unique_ptr<int>( new int(3) ) ); // before c++14
    ...
}
```

and you do not need to implement dtor explicitly, you do not violate the rule and it is safe to pass dynamically allocated data to ctor.

Note: I assumed you used `int` as example and you would understand that dynamically allocate one `int` is useless, you should just store it by value.

Comment: If i will add copy constructor and change code like these:
`int *p= new int(3);
test a(p);
delete p;`
Is it okay ?

Comment: @LukaMamulaishvili copy constructor *and* assignment operator (rule of 3). Both with move semantics, too, to fit the rule of five. Apart from that, you are right...

Comment: @LukaMamulaishvili By the way, for the temporary array, you *can* go another way, too: allocate it on the stack: `int p[] = { 3 }; test a(p);` (sure, not always appropriate, but if, ...).

Comment: @LukaMamulaishvili it is okeish, but this code is error prone and more important it is unreadable. It would be totally unclear for a reader why you need to allocate it, pass to ctor and then immediately destroy it.

Comment: @Aconcagua you do not need to create an array, just pass pointer to an `int` variable.

Comment: So is it better to create object in main and delete it ? Without pointers inside class?

Comment: @Slava Totally clear... Just as you *asumed* that the class is designed to take ownership of the array, I assumed the array is needed by design (in a different szenario with more than one value) and the code here is just an example...

Comment: @LukaMamulaishvili Sometimes yes, sometimes no. It depends on the use case, software requirements, ...

Answer (score 3):

You are violating the rule of 3 (5 since c++11). It means that since you defined the destructor you should define the copy/move constructor/operation.

With your implementation, the copy/move constructor/operation are wrong. When you copy your object, it will do a shallow copy of your pointer and will delete it therefore you will have a double delete. When you move it, you will delete a pointer you didn't allocated.

Bonus point: your inline is useless